# Regex to tokenize string to a class

Tags: c#, regex, text-parsing

```
msiinv  2015\03\22  14:58:10

SSMSBoost for SSMS 2012
    Product code:   {94EDFFE7-E4F4-4C9B-A57E-C7267BB4A777}
    Product state:  (5) Installed.
    Assignment: per user
    Package code:   {5D9DA43D-E03A-4420-A8AF-3D2FFBA1A696}
    Version:    2.15.5473.18051
    Publisher:  Solutions Crew
    Language:   1033
    Installed from: C:\Users\EffiaSoft\Downloads\
        Package:    SSMSBoostInstaller2012_2.15.5473.18051.msi
    Product Icon:   %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Installer\{94EDFFE7-E4F4-4C9B-A57E-C7267BB4A777}\icon.ico
    Instance type:  0
    Local package:  C:\Windows\Installer\58b9554a.msi
    Install date:   2015\01\22
    0 patch packages.

Microsoft Application Error Reporting
    Product code:   {95120000-00B9-0409-0000-0000000FF1CE}
    Product state:  (5) Installed.
    Assignment: per machine
    Package code:   {420F351B-33A5-4A58-A856-69B2EDEDC8F7}
    Version:    12.0.6012.5000
    Publisher:  Microsoft Corporation
    Language:   1033
    Installed from: c:\f04684676d077419cb\redist\watson\
        Package:    dw20shared.msi
    About link: http://support.microsoft.com
    Help link:  http://support.microsoft.com
    Instance type:  0
    Local package:  c:\Windows\Installer\913d6.msi
    Install date:   2014\03\19
    0 patch packages.
```

I'm trying to tokenize this text. The result that I expect is a class call `Software` which will have properties as `ProductCode`, `ProductState` and all other properties defined in the text and populate that with the values after the colon. So parsing this file would give me list of `Software` class. How do you think I should proceed with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not able to comment because of my rep (which is a bit stupid) but here is my suggestion.

It probably is not going to be a clean solution but if that is your only output then you could always split the string up by line breaks and then loop around the array that it gives you and use the following regex to get the value before the first semi-colon

```
^\D+(?=:\s)
```

you would then need to have some sort of switch to work out what property of the software class you would need to put it in. It may be messy but it looks as though with the outputted text it would be pretty safe to assume it's going to be largely the same.
With there being variable amounts of spaces tabs and different characters to get the value for the property I would simply just use the regex above to replace the property name with nothing and then the rest of that array would be your value. This would be reducing the amount of regex you need to use which is generally a better thing.

psuedo code wise would be

```
Split string up by new line characters
loop through collection of strings
    Run the regex ^\D+(?=:\s)
    switch on the regex string to find the property name
        replace property name with blank space using the regex  ^\D+:\s+
        using the rest of the string as the value set the property.
```

I don't know why you have been marked down, I suspect that its because you mentioned regex. If possible, the nicer solution (and one which may not get marked down) would be to convert the text file into an xml file. I don't know how possible it is for your output but make it a lot better solution.

EDIT: updated the regex to work with the exceptions in the comment.

Comment: agreed, investigating if there are any other formats for the output would my first step rather than trying to process this.

Comment: This is exactly what I've done. But I'm having problem splitting the value with regex for e.g - ` Installed from: C:\Users\EffiaSoft\Downloads\` and ` Product code: {94EDFFE7-E4F4-4C9B-A57E-C7267BB4A777}`. Now because there is path in the variable value which also contains the `:(COLON)` character simple splitting is not working. Can you please provide me with a regex for this.

Comment: I've updated the regex now. It will take into account spaces between words and should stop at the first colon. I have just had a thought, when you are replacing the string you may want to change the regex to remove the positive lookahead i.e use ^\D+:\s+ that should strip out the whitespace before the value.

Comment: I'll admit the edited regex I put in the answer is possibly a bit hacky so if it doesnt work try using this site https://regex101.com/ to play around with it a little. let me know if you have any more problems

Comment: I've tested the regex now the property name is not being captured by the regex `^\D+(?=:\s)`.

Comment: What is the regex statement matching on? It's possible that it is picking up the white spaces and then when that's going into the switch its not able to compare them. You could always try using string.trim or something to remove the leading and trailing white spaces. This is why people tend to avoid regex because it is difficult to get it perfect and it sometimes performs differently from the regex websites and in code.